# adding in ArrayList without iterating

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to create an `ArrayList<Float>` of length 350. I did this:

```
x = new ArrayList<Float>(350);
```

No i want this array to have 'zero' float value at each point. i can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 350 ; i++){
            x.add((float) 0.0);
}
```

So my question is if there is another way to do the same thing without iterating. I want minimum iterating to increase efficiency.

Comment: `O(n)` is pretty efficient. You should worry about making other, less efficient areas, more efficient. You cannot initialize an arraylist with default values. The constructor only allows for a cap, nothing, or a collection of values.

Comment: You can create a float literal by writing `0.0f`. That way you don't need to cast it to float. But note that using double instead of float is a good decision in most cases, because almost all Java math functions take and return doubles. When you also use doubles, you avoid unnecessary casting.

Comment: i am using float because it is smaller than double and takes up smaller space comparatively. I am dealing with lots of huge arrays here so i thought maybe float will be a better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want efficiency I wouldn't use `ArrayList` or `Float` here. I wouldn't recommend using `float` even as it's precision is so poor, unless you really know what you are doing.

I suggest you use an array of double.

```
double[] x = new double[350]; // all 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

java's `Collections` class has a nice utility for this: [`nCopies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29). Note that this creates an immutable list, but it does exactly what you want :)

Comment: The `nCopies` method also does a loop for the number of elements that you specify, so with regard to "I want minimum iterating to increase efficiency" this doesn't win you anything.

Comment: @jlordo It was a guess and you're right, it [doesn't loop](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.nCopies%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) - but it does return a `List` which you cannot modify, so that limits its usage.

Comment: @soulcheck and Jesper: akaIDIOT stated the fact that it's immutable in the answer...

Comment: @jlordo haha looks like i skipped half of it. tl;dr taken to the extreme :)

Answer (score 0):

From java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList(int initialCapacity) 
          Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
```

Note the list is still **empty** so you have to add the elements one by one. Only capacity is changed.

I would advice you to construct another collection for instance an array and then initialize the list using that constructor:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) 
          Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.
```

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says use an array. If you want this in an array list you can use the code below. This creates an arraylist of 100 integers each with a value of 42

```
 Integer[] a = new Integer[100];
 Arrays.fill(a, 42);
 List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
 for (Integer integer : l) {
      System.out.println(integer);
 }
```

You can modify it easily to be of type Float and assign any initial value you want.